# Angular keyvalue pipe not able to infer type correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

Template:

```
<div class="main">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let threshold of durationThreshold | keyvalue"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularTest';

  public durationThreshold : Record<string, {
    timeInSeconds: number | undefined,
    unit: string
  }> = {}

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Keyvalue source code (From angular source):

```
export declare class KeyValuePipe implements PipeTransform {
    private readonly differs;
    constructor(differs: KeyValueDiffers);
    private differ;
    private keyValues;
    private compareFn;
    transform<K, V>(input: ReadonlyMap<K, V>, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<K, V>, b: KeyValue<K, V>) => number): Array<KeyValue<K, V>>;
    transform<K extends number, V>(input: Record<K, V>, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<string, V>, b: KeyValue<string, V>) => number): Array<KeyValue<string, V>>;
    transform<K extends string, V>(input: Record<K, V> | ReadonlyMap<K, V>, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<K, V>, b: KeyValue<K, V>) => number): Array<KeyValue<K, V>>;
    transform(input: null | undefined, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<unknown, unknown>, b: KeyValue<unknown, unknown>) => number): null;
    transform<K, V>(input: ReadonlyMap<K, V> | null | undefined, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<K, V>, b: KeyValue<K, V>) => number): Array<KeyValue<K, V>> | null;
    transform<K extends number, V>(input: Record<K, V> | null | undefined, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<string, V>, b: KeyValue<string, V>) => number): Array<KeyValue<string, V>> | null;
    transform<K extends string, V>(input: Record<K, V> | ReadonlyMap<K, V> | null | undefined, compareFn?: (a: KeyValue<K, V>, b: KeyValue<K, V>) => number): Array<KeyValue<K, V>> | null;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<KeyValuePipe, never>;
    static ɵpipe: ɵngcc0.ɵɵPipeDeclaration<KeyValuePipe, "keyvalue">;
}
```

IntelliJ is reporting the following error in template:

> Argument type Record<string, {timeInSeconds: number | undefined, unit:
> string}> is not assignable to parameter type ReadonlyMap<unknown,
> unknown>

From the keyvalue source code it should match the third overload. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems that the problem is specific to IntelliJ as in VSCode there is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-51209](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51209), please follow it for updates